# How to add a new method to Eigen3 base class?

Tags: eigen3

I want to a simple method to copy a matrix using Eigen3 MatrixXd class. For that I create a header file with the new method and I use the macro  uEIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN to include in the compilation.

I want to create a method named copyMatrix() that simply is identical to do
A = B
but in this format:
A.copyMatrix(B).

When I try to code it with the following code:

```
template<typename OtherDerived>
inline void copyMatrix(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other) const
{
    derived() = other.derived();
}
```

I have compilation errors such as:
 error C2678: binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Eigen::Matrix' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Which is correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your method `copyMatrix` is `const`, just remove it:

```
template<typename OtherDerived>
inline void copyMatrix(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)
{
    derived() = other.derived();
}
```